# How to get a value from table which is present in another table by criteria

Tags: mysql, hive, hadoop2

```
Table A
----------
Roll NO
1
2

Table B :
---------
ROllNo , Date                                         
1,            2012
1,                                                            
2,            2013
2,            2014
```

for eg :

I should get result roll no: 2, since the record from table A should be shown in the result set only when that particular key is present in table B with dates.In this above example only roll no 2 from table A has 2 records in Table B. Please help me to get the result.

Comment: Both keys are present in table b with dates

Comment: @Strawberry but only the entries for `1` have a NULL date.

Comment: so, you want rollnos that are not associated with null (or 'blank') dates. In which case, Tordek's solutions appear valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to select all values which have a NULL date, and then select all of the values which do not appear in that list:

```
SELECT Roll
FROM table
WHERE Roll NOT IN (SELECT Roll
                   FROM table
                   WHERE date IS NULL)
```

Another option, using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Roll
FROM table
GROUP BY Roll
HAVING COUNT(date IS NULL) = 0;
```